# how to fix npm audit error with loadVirtual and ENOLOCK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

```
➜   npm audit
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file
```

I ran npm audit and got this error.

When I run below:

```
➜ npm config get package-lock
true

➜ npm config get shrinkwrap
true
```

Can anybody help with this? as to how to fix it? and npm audit fix --force is not working as well...

Comment: Try deleting `package-lock.json`

Comment: Did you initialize npm in your project folder using `npm init`? After that, just type `npm i --package-lock-only`. Should see no err or vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 25):

I just ran the command it says to.

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

Then it showed me 0 vulnerabilities.
Anyway, ran again **audit fix** and again 0 vulnerabilities.

Comment: this resolved the warning of vulnerabilities for me.  why does this happen?  is it something that could be added to the install.  i'm using this to install homebridge on ubuntu, fresh install, and am told there are problems immediately after the initial install.  recommendations for bug reporting process?

Answer (score 24):

works for me like this:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: what does `npm fund` do?

Comment: this worked for me without the `npm fund` command

Comment: `npm fund` command is not required.

Running the other two commands to clean the cache and force fixing the audit identified issues helped me.

Ensure that you run the `npm audit fix --force` command in a directory with **package.json** and **package-lock.json** files. Running the audit command in any other directory fails.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is that you need a **package.json** and **package-lock.json** file in the directory.

Running the following commands will fix it for you.

```
npm init -y

npm i --package-lock-only

npm audit
```

This fixes the problem

Comment: For future answers, I can recommend presenting CLI commands and source code in the form of code fences/blocks. Code blocks easily stand out from the text and increase the readability of an answer.

Answer (score 8):

That error tells you the root of the problem: `This command requires an existing lockfile.`. This implies that you don't already have a `package-lock.json` along side the `package.json` you're trying to audit. `npm i --package-lock-only` just generates/updates package-lock.json without reinstalling; `npm i` would reinstall and generate one (based on your config).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create package-lock.json, run

```
npm install
```

then

```
npm audit fix
```

you won't have the problem

Answer (score 1):

I updated to the latest version of npm with  `npm install -g npm@8.3.0`, and now it shows no more problems...

Answer (score 1):

Try running these:

```
npm i --package-lock-only
npm config get package-lock
npm config get shrinkwrap
npm i --package-lock-only
npm audit fix
```

From [here](https://medium.com/illumination/how-to-fix-npm-audit-error-with-loadvirtual-and-enolock-deprecated-dependencies-1f07ba65eef9).

Answer (score 0):

Use Node 14, it fixed the issue with 0 vulnerabilities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I read this and really helpful:

https://medium.com/illumination/how-to-fix-npm-audit-error-with-loadvirtual-and-enolock-deprecated-dependencies-1f07ba65eef9

```
npm i --package-lock-only
npm config get package-lock
npm config get shrinkwrap
npm i --package-lock-only
npm audit fix
```

(When running ‘npm config get package-lock’ and ‘npm config get shrinkwrap’, you will receive ‘true’ for both)
— → After running ‘npm audit fix’, you will see: “up to date, audited… found 0 vulnerabilities”

Answer (score 0):

`npm cache verify` fixed it for me.

For those who were suggesting `npm cache clean --force`, read the following. When I ran `npm cache clean`, I received the following message:

As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result, data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify` instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same error, then realized I was in a parent folder. So this may happen if there's no lock file.

Answer (score -2):

Try running this command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```